# An invalid form control with name='location[]' is not focusable. even thought i remove the required attribute from hidden input

Tags: jquery, google-chrome

I have a radio button with name "country" and attribute required. Even though I remove that attribute, the chrome browser still shows the error that the specific field can not be focusable?!

```
$('.location-new > div > input').removeAttr('required');
```

Comment: Share the relevant code snippets you have tried so far.

Comment: Have you tried `$('.location-new > div > input').prop('required', false)`?

Comment: Yes i tried that too, but was not the solution to the problem, it has to do with some chrome version. I switched to jsut js validation and removed the html5 validation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's a bug in some recent versions of Chrome that affects this specific situation (radio input, required attribute removed by JavaScript):

[checkValidity() yields false when required property removed with JavaScript in Chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36346858/checkvalidity-yields-false-when-required-property-removed-with-javascript-in-c)

Google doesn't seem to have acknowledged it yet, though:

https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=599040

Comment: Thank you for the comment that seems really to be a chrome problem, i removed the html5 validation and inserted just js validation to solve.